# Isomorphisms and Implicit Function Theorem in the context of Hilbert spaces

Tags: hilbert-spaces, implicit-function-theorem, vector-space-isomorphism

Let X be a Hilbert space with inner product denoted $(\cdot,\cdot)$ and norm $\|\cdot\|$ induced by it. Suppose $F\,\colon\,X \times \mathbb{R} \to X$ is continuously Frechet differentiable with respect to both variables. Assume $(x_0,y_0)$ are such that $F(x_0,y_0) = 0$. Define
$$
T\,\colon\,X \to X\quad \text{ with }\quad Tx = DF(x_0,y_0)(x,0)
$$
and assume that it is an isomorphism, which in particular implies that there exist constants $C,D >0$ such that 
$$
C\|x\| \leq \|Tx\| \leq D \|x\|.\quad (1)
$$
Does it imply that there exists $\lambda >0$ such that
$$
(Tx,x) \geq \lambda (x,x)\,\forall x \in X?\quad (2)
$$
Am I missing something absolutely obvious? Does (1) straightfowardly imply (2)?

Futhermore, this setup permits us to apply Implicit Function Theorem for Banach spaces (as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Generalizations)) to conclude that there is some neighbourhood $U\subset X$ around $x_0$ and some interval $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ around $y_0$ and some Frechet differentiable function $g\,\colon\,\mathbb{R}\to X$ such that $F(g(y),y) = 0$ and $F(x,y) = 0$ iff $x = g(y)$ for all $(x,y) \in U \times I$.

Again, is it obvious that then (2) applies to $g(y_1) \in X$ for any $y_1 \in I?$ Is it a consequence the fact that $x\mapsto D(g(y_1),y_1)(x,0)$ is also an isomorphism? Is it?

Comment: Perhaps I should add that in the example I am working on it turns out that in fact $Tx = \lambda x$ for some $\lambda > 0$, which immediately gives us (2), so perhaps (2) may not be true for any isomorphism, but then I am still interested to find out how IFT preserves this property.